# Matrix Plot: How to Apply color function to only a region of the plot

Tags: plotting, graphics, matrix, color

I want to make a matrix plot where a color function is applied to a region of a matrix. Those matrix elements which were not in the region specified should not have any color associated with them, and they should display the numerical value of that matrix element.

Specifically,  I have a matrix that is 8 columns big. I want to make a matrix plot where the first seven columns to have a color function applied to them.  The 8th column should simply be uncolored and should display the numerical value associated with that matrix element.

To contextualize the data, each row of the matrix represents a molecule.  Each column represents the charge on a particular carbon atom.  The final column is the equilibrium constant for a chemical reaction associated with each atom.  The goal is to correlate the charge on each atom with the equilibrium constant.

```
data = {{0.462, -0.195, -0.364, -0.331, -0.248, -0.183, 
 0.329, -1}, {0.462, -0.195, -0.364, -0.331, -0.248, -0.183, 
 0.329, -1}, {0.307, -0.12, -0.332, -0.328, -0.332, -0.12, 0.307, 
 0.0672}, {0.22, -0.147, -0.328, -0.391, -0.328, -0.147, 0.22, 
 0.011}, {0.275, -0.108, -0.327, -0.344, -0.327, -0.108, 0.275, 
 0.0363}, {0.291, -0.164, -0.258, -0.343, -0.268, -0.164, 
 0.291, -1}, {0.391, -0.2, -0.242, -0.349, -0.242, -0.2, 
 0.391, -1}, {0.448, -0.237, -0.232, -0.333, -0.232, -0.237, 0.448, 
 1}, {0.472, -0.208, -0.226, -0.379, -0.226, -0.2, 0.472, 
 0.261}, {0.347, -0.246, -0.161, -0.359, -0.161, -0.246, 0.347, 20}}
```

[image]

I want the first 7 columns to have the color map.  And the 8th column to display the number associated with that matrix element.

Comment: @MarcoB  How did you get the image to display correctly?  I couldn't figure it out

Comment: You had the link indented by 4 spaces, so the system interpreted it as code instead. I just had to remove the extra leading spaces. As an aside, are you sure of the values in your last column? Equilibrium constants should be positive numbers, but you have some negative values there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Updated code**

Based on some wonderful comments below, here is some simplified, more robust code.

```
MatrixPlot[
 PadRight[Drop[data, None, -1], Dimensions[data]]
 , ColorRules -> {0 -> White}
 , Epilog -> MapIndexed[
     Text[#1, Flatten[{Last[Dimensions[data]] - 0.5, #2 - 0.5}]] &
     , Reverse@data[[All, -1]]
   ]
]
```

**Original code**

Does this do the trick? It's sort of messy, but it does what I think what you want.

```
MatrixPlot[
  Transpose@Insert[
    Transpose[data][[;; -2]]
    , ConstantArray[0, Length@data]
    , -1
  ]
  , ColorRules -> {0 -> White}
  , Epilog -> MapIndexed[
      Text[#1, Flatten[{Length@Transpose@data - 0.5, #2 - 0.5}]] &
      , Reverse@data[[All, -1]]
    ]
  ]
```

*Updates*: Based on the good comment below, I've added `ColorRules -> {0 -> White}` in order to assure that the last column will always be white no matter what `ColorFunction` is used. In addition, I have made this more general by using the `Length` of `Transpose@data` in order to place the text, rather than putting in `8` by hand.

The result looks like this:

[image]

I've replaced the final column in `data` with a column of zeros, and I've fed the last column of data to `Text`'s which are placed using `Epilog`. The use of `MapIndexed` might be overkill, but it works.

Comment: You could use `ColorRules->{0->White}` to make sure that any applied `ColorFunction` makes that last column white.

Comment: Yes, that is a good idea. I will add it to the code.

Comment: Consider `PadRight[Drop[data, None, -1], Dimensions[data]]`…

Comment: @J. M. Much more beautiful than mine. Thank you. I will update the answer.

Comment: Also, prolly better to do `Last[Dimensions[data]]` than `Length[Transpose[data]]`.

Comment: @J. M. Yes. Fixed. At what point does this become your answer? :)

Comment: No point at all. It's still your sculpture, and I'm just holding the sandpaper… ;)

Comment: Is it possible to add a legend onto this plot?   `PlotLegends -> Placed[Automatic , Right]` does not produce a legend

Comment: `PlotLegends -> Automatic` seems to work for me, although the legend is relatively small.

Comment: @march for some reason with both versions of your code `PlotLegends -> Automatic` does not generate a legend for me.  Other than that, this answer is exactly what I want.  I'll accept an answer tomorrow, but I want to wait a day in case others also want to answer.

Comment: @olliepower. It looks to me like `ColorRules` is interfering with `PlotLegends` for some reason. If you remove the `ColorRules` option, the legend should appear, and this will be fine as long as you don't change the `ColorFunction`.

Comment: @march  that resolved the issue.  Thank you guys so much!

Answer (score 4):

Another way using `Graphics` primitives `Raster` and `Text`:

```
dimdata = Reverse@Dimensions@data;

map = data[[All, ;; -2]] // Raster[#, {{0, 0}, Reverse@Dimensions@#}, MinMax@#, 
ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"] &;

text = Text @@@ Thread[{data[[All, -1]], 
Thread@{First@dimdata, Range[Last@dimdata]} - 0.5}];
```

then

```
Graphics[{map, text}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, Frame -> True, 
 PlotRange -> Thread[{0, dimdata}], PlotRangePadding -> 0.3, 
 FrameTicks -> ((Range[#] // Thread@{# - 0.5, #} &) & /@ dimdata)]
```

[image]